Restricting Google API keys with SHA-1 on Google Play console blocks usage of app
I have a published android app on Google Play which I built with Expo and React Native.
I am trying to restrict my Google API key for just the Android App itself, here:

I choose "Android apps" and then I need to add an item with a package name and SHA-1 certificate fingerprint.

I added 2 items. One for the production release, and one for the expo dev build.
The Expo item uses the SHA-1 fingerprint that I obtain with the terminal command eas credentials for my dev build (the SHA-1 is the same for dev and prod).
The release item uses the SHA-1 fingerprint specified by the Google Play console in the 'App Signing' section, called "SHA-1 certificate fingerprint" (which google console provides on its own via App Signing)
After this, features in my app that rely on the APIs, do not work.
For example I query google places api and the maps SDK and it usually returns places and map markers etc.
With these restrictions, it doesn't work.
If I put back the restrictions to 'None', it works.
Can anyone explain please why the SHA-1 from google itself doesn't allow my app to work on user's end devices..?
Thanks for your time :)
I tried setting SHA-1 fingerprints in restricting API keys and access to the android app.
Resetting restrictions back to 'None' works.
